# ZF2 Howto pass model object to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2, modal-dialog

I have an index view in which I iterate over a collection of model objects. Each model object can be deleted. After clicking the delete button a modal is used.

```
<div class="panel-group ng-isolate-scope">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->url('label', array('order_by' => 'name', 'order' => $url_order)); ?>">
                    Name 
                    <?php if ($order_by == 'name'): ?>
                        <i class="icon-chevron-<?php echo $url_order == 'ASC' ? 'down' : 'up' ?>"></i>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($paginator as $label) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $label->getId(); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $label->getName(); ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->url('label', array('controller' => 'label', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => $label->getId())); ?>">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $label->getId() ?>" data-target="#delete-label-modal" href="<?php echo $this->url('label', array('controller' => 'label', 'action' => 'delete', 'id' => $label->getId())); ?>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<!--/ Delete Label Modal -->
<?= $this->partial('deleteLabel', array('label' => $label)) ?>
```

The `deleteLabel` partial looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-label-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delete-label-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="delete-label-modal-label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure that you want to delete
                '<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($label->getName()); ?>'?
            </div>

            <?php
            $url = $this->url('label', array(
                'action' => 'delete',
                'id' => $label->getId(),
            ));
            ?>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post">
                    <div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (int) $label->getId(); ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="delete" value="Yes" />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="delete" value="No" />
                    </div>
                </form>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with the initial code is that it only passes the last label after iteration and off course it should pass the label based on data-id of the clicked label.

Could anyone help me out how to obtain a model object after click and pass it to the modal?

Answer (score 0):

It's cause your partial call is out of your loop ;)

you should probably do something like that :

```
<?php $renderPartial = ''; ?> 
<?php foreach ($paginator as $label) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $label->getId(); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $label->getName(); ?></td>
                <td><a href="<?php echo $this->url('label', array('controller' => 'label', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => $label->getId())); ?>">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $label->getId() ?>" data-target="#delete-label-modal" href="<?php echo $this->url('label', array('controller' => 'label', 'action' => 'delete', 'id' => $label->getId())); ?>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
    <?php $renderPartial .= $this->partial('deleteLabel', array('label' => $label)) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
...
<?= $renderPartial; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am one step further in the generated source it now shows multiple partials generated with the correct content. However if the modal opens it does not show the correct content it opens a modal showing the index which I am starting the operation from in Modal. Do you have any idea how I can make sure it opens the correct dialog?

Comment: for each modal you have to make a target : data-target="#delete-label-modal" and your's is always the same. try something like :  data-target="#delete-label-modal-<?php echo $label->getId(); ?>"